# downloading .xls file doesn't gives data within file in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want data into .xls file...but it doesn't give....

```
$this->load->view("partial/footer_excel");
$content = ob_end_flush();

$filename = trim($filename);
$filename = str_replace(array(' ', '/', '\\'), '', $title);
$filename .= "_Export.xls";
ob_clean();
ob_start();
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $content;
die();
```

Comment: How is that related to javascript/jquery?

Comment: i want this in PHP...